# XamlParseException when using converter

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, ivalueconverter

I getting XamlParseException when try to use converter. I suspect that I made a mistake in converter but can't catch it.

Full error text:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.ni.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot create instance of type
>   'app.Converters.DimensionToText' [Line: 21 Position: 42]

```
namespace app.Converters
{
    class DimensionToText : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Dimensions dim = (Dimensions) value;
            //bool param = (bool) parameter;
            return dim.width.ToString().Trim() + "\"x " + dim.length.ToString().Trim() + "\"x " + dim.height.ToString().Trim() + "\"";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML parts:

```
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:app.Converters"
...
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <converter:DimensionToText x:Key="DimensionToText"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
...
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"> 
    <Run Text="Dimensions:"/>
    <Run Text="{Binding information.dimensions, Converter={StaticResource DimensionToText}}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Strangely in design time converter works just fine. Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: Does making the converter a public class change the behavior?

Comment: @Vkt0rS. Your edit did not improve the formatting here. It just made the error harder to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your converter `public`

```
namespace app.Converters
{
    public class DimensionToText : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Dimensions dim = (Dimensions) value;
            //bool param = (bool) parameter;
            return dim.width.ToString().Trim() + "\"x " + dim.length.ToString().Trim() + "\"x " + dim.height.ToString().Trim() + "\"";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```